# merging multidimensional arrays(PHP)

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

Say I have a couple multi-demensional arrays with the same structure like so:

```
Array ( [0] => Tips Object ( [id] => 1 [userId] => 10 )
    [1] => Tips Object ( [id] => 2 [userId] => 22 )
    [2] => Tips Object ( [id] => 3 [userId] => 33 )
    [3] => Tips Object ( [id] => 7 [userId] => 77 ) ) 


Array ( [0] => Tips Object ( [id] => 2 [userId] => 22 )
    [1] => Tips Object ( [id] => 3 [userId] => 33 )
    [2] => Tips Object ( [id] => 4 [userId] => 44 )
    [3] => Tips Object ( [id] => 5 [userId] => 55 )
    [4] => Tips Object ( [id] => 6 [userId] => 66 ) )
```

I need a way to merge them in a way so I would get this:

```
Array ( [0] => Tips Object ( [id] => 1 [userId] => 10 )
    [1] => Tips Object ( [id] => 2 [userId] => 22 )
    [2] => Tips Object ( [id] => 3 [userId] => 33 )
    [3] => Tips Object ( [id] => 4 [userId] => 44 )
    [4] => Tips Object ( [id] => 5 [userId] => 55 )
    [5] => Tips Object ( [id] => 6 [userId] => 66 )
    [6] => Tips Object ( [id] => 7 [userId] => 77 ) )
```

The real multi dimensional array will be more complicated, this one is just to help explain what I need.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Where are userids 20 and 30 in the final array?

Comment: I have Changed my question, Please help

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you are trying to do is merge two sorted sequences (by id or userid) into a final sorted sequence. In that case, have a look over the merge procedure used as part of MergeSort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Algorithm

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1=array(  0=>array('id'=>'1','userid'=>'10'),
                1=>array('id'=>'2','userid'=>'22'),
                2=>array('id'=>'3','userid'=>'33'),
                3=>array('id'=>'7','userid'=>'77'));

$array2=array(  0=>array('id'=>'2','userid'=>'22'),
                1=>array('id'=>'3','userid'=>'33'),
                2=>array('id'=>'4','userid'=>'44'),
                3=>array('id'=>'5','userid'=>'55'),
                4=>array('id'=>'6','userid'=>'66'));

echo "<pre>";

$mix = array();
foreach($array2 as $k=>$value)
{
    if(!in_array($value,array_values($array1))){
        $array1[] = $value;
    }
}


function sortById($a, $b) {
    return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
}
usort($array1, 'sortById');
print_r($array1);
exit;
```